# how to add(link) my customized javascript code to any html/php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, customization, external

i would like to add javascript to an html page. I don't want to have those scripts inline on the home page however, I would like them to be in an external javascript file. How do I link to an external javascript file so those scripts are run on the page?

```
<html>
<head> <title>asc Computer Grass Roots pvt. ltd.</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
        <script>    my jquesry scrips here
        </script>
</head> 
<body>  somecodes </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: The same way you added the jquery.js file. `<script src="yourScriptsFile.js"></script>`

Comment: @people : stop downvoting questions just because you think that's too easy. The OP may be a simple sunday coder. Even it is easy to find on google : read the question title and you will see that the OP is not familiar with this topic and may not search for it the right way.

Comment: Seven downvotes (as of the time I write this) is probably a bit harsh on a newcomer. Pradipta, don't be discouraged by this. That just means that your question is more of a newbie question than most here expect. Your question could have been answered using google instead of a q&a site. Try to keep that in mind, but feel free to ask questions when you need help.

Comment: @TecBrat and I gave my upvote to balance this...

Comment: @Apolo thank you so much ,actually you can call me newbie on this web developing,that's why i have asked here,thank you all of you guys who did not down vote me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<script>my jquesry scrips here</script>
```

put

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Of course you will have to create a file named 'myscript.js' and type javascript code in it.

Answer (score 1):

In the map of your website create a file called script.js
put your jquery script in there
replace:

```
<script>my jquery scrips here</script>
```

with:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

just like you did with the jquery.js, next time search the web before asking questions on SO.

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp)
if you google "link javascript file" the first link is your answer to the question (link above is the website).

Comment: You need to edit: you wrote "jquery.js" instead of "script.js" (as you named it)

Comment: Woops I was a bit to quick, thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 1):

For example, let say that you have all your javascript code in a file called 'functions.js', to link that javascript file to your html page just do it the same way you linked you jquery file.

```
<html>
<head> <title>asc Computer Grass Roots pvt. ltd.</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="functions.js"></script> <!-- linking your file -->
    <script>
        /*my jquery scripts here */
    </script>
</head> 
    <body>  somecodes </body> 
</html>
```

Keep in mind that if the code in your 'functions.js' file needs jQuery to work correctly you have to add 'jquery.js' before adding your custom file, just as it is in the example.

Comment: you could have removed `<script>my jquesry scrips here</script>` which will cause an error